# Convert list of Google Maps links to exact address

Tags: google-maps, street-address

I have a list of addresses in a csv. Eg:

https://www.google.com/maps/place/Cahoots+London/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x487604d507ab69fb:0xbbfbc270f421a878
[https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mr+Fogg's+Gin+Parlour/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x487604cdb617ba29:0xcef59d8e87aa23df](https://www.google.com/maps/place/Mr+Fogg%27s+Gin+Parlour/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x487604cdb617ba29:0xcef59d8e87aa23df)

I want to convert these into the exact address from maps i.e.

13 Kingly Ct, Carnaby, London W1B 5PW
1 New Row, London WC2N 4EA

Is there an easy way to do it in bulk for 500+ URLs?

PS: Haven't tried using Google APIs yet

Answer (score 0):

*You may try:*

```js
=let(Σ,importxml(A2,"//meta[@property='og:title']/@content"),
 mid(Σ,find("·",Σ)+2,9^9))
```

[image]

- *excessive usage of import functions can result in a scenario of `import_data loading forever` in the sheet. I'd suggest to do few hundreds at a time → **then copy-paste the output addresses as values** which effectively removes the import formulas for those cells that are done.*